# Concurrent (video) streams with Flask

Tags: python, flask, concurrency, proxy, stream

I'm trying to MITM proxy for a application that doesn't provide a proper API layer (yet), this is what I've come up with so far:

```
@app.route('/auto/<channel>')
def stream(channel):
    url = ''
    channel = channel.replace('v', '')

    if not request.args.get('duration'):
        duration = 60 * 60  # set default timeout to 1h if not set
    else:
        duration = int(request.args.get('duration'))
    duration += time.time()

    for c in _get_channels():
        if str(c['number']) == channel:
            url = '%s%s%s' % (config['tvhURL'], '/stream/channel/', c['uuid'])

    if not url:
        abort(404)
    else:
        req = requests.get(url, stream=True)

        def generate():
            for chunk in req.iter_content(chunk_size=10*1024):
                if not time.time() < duration:
                    req.close()
                yield chunk

        return Response(generate(), content_type=req.headers['content-type'], direct_passthrough=True)
```

Now it works perfectly fine for one (live video) stream but will block any other requests/streams for as long as the stream is active.

I've been looking for an awnser for a while now, and seem's I've come to the conclusion that this is a limitation within Flask and it's synchronous nature.

But I'm still hopeing that someone would prove me wrong as I like working with Flask.

So question is; can multiple concurrent streams be supported? And if yes, an example would be nice.

Comment: Flask is the wrong tool for building an MITM proxy as you are correct that it is synchronous.

Comment: @metatoaster do you have any alternative suggestions? perferebly python based

Comment: Try [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/), since you are trying to do this using the `yield` keyword which is one piece of the patterns they use. There are MITM proxy implementations done using this out there, just search using these keywords.

Comment: Roger that @metatoaster. As a final question, would using gevent and monkey patching actully help? http://www.gevent.org/intro.html#monkey-patching

Comment: Maybe, depends on what you are doing.

Comment: Does this mean that we cannot have a flask application serving a different stream for each user connecting to the application ? @metatoaster

Comment: @021 at the time this question was asked, yes, but there may have been changes done to Flask that make this not strictly the case. Their development server definitely still have this issue and hence in the debug log it explicitly states that the development server is not for production usage.

Comment: @metatoaster Thanks for the information ! Would you advise against trying to do concurrent video streaming with Flask ? What alternatives would you recommend in Python ? If you have some articles/tutorial or somehwere to point me to on this matter I'd gladly take it. Thank you :)